# How to detect a full page Refresh/Reload in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to detect a page refresh in Blazor, So that before the refresh occures, I save some data to local storage, I tried Dispose, But the services that I get Data to save are not available at this stage.
I also tried JavaScript's window.onbeforeunload and calling a C# method when this occures as follows:

```
public static class SessionSaver
{
    [JSInvokable]
    public static Task SaveServicesToSession()
    {
        ViewDataService viewData = (ViewDataService)GetMeSomeServiceLocator.Instance.GetService(typeof(ViewDataService));           
        ProtectedBrowserStorage protectedBrowserStorage = (ProtectedBrowserStorage)GetMeSomeServiceLocator.Instance.GetService(typeof(ProtectedSessionStorage));
        protectedBrowserStorage.SetAsync("ViewData", viewData);
        protectedBrowserStorage.SetAsync("AuthModel", viewData.AuthModel);            
        return Task.FromResult("Success.");
    }
}
```

Javascript:

```
 window.onbeforeunload  = () => {
        DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('BlazorStore9', 'SaveServicesToSession')
            .then(message => { console.log(message); });
        }
```

Startup.cs: a nested class:

```
 public static class GetMeSomeServiceLocator
    {
        public static IServiceProvider Instance { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the configure method:

```
GetMeSomeServiceLocator.Instance = app.ApplicationServices;
```

The JsInvokable is called when I reload the page but I get error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'BlazorStore9.Services.ViewDataService' from root provider.'

Is there anything can be done to solve this problem?

Comment: onbeforeunload is a good option or you could find other events in the normal workflow of your application to save the data. I don't know what you mean by it "requires a message from blazor" -  maybe add some detail about that to your question so it is more targetted to a specific problem

Comment: In blazor if we want to call a c# method from JavaScript. The JavaScript method should be called from blazor . It could not be initiated purely by a JavaScript event.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that was true? It's not. There is explicitly the function to invoke dotnet methods for this reason. (I have done exactly what you are trying previously)

Comment: As suggested previously - please update your question with a specific question about a specific problem, show what you tried and any errors you received. That is how this site works - focus on a single problem, and it makes it easier to help. Did you try the method you wanted to use? It says you did, but there is no code and no error messages.

Comment: Yes correct I get it wrong with calling c# instance methods by JavaScript that requires the instance is passed by c# code.

Comment: I will try the JavaScript onbeforeunload that calls static c# method and post the results here.

Comment: You can still call an instance method for this, as long as you have stored the dotnetref somewhere - so for instance, you can pass a reference to JS from your "App" component (or any persistent component) when it is first rendered and store that in the "window" for later use in onbeforeunload.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the comments from @Mister Magoo and @mz1378 and [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1), I created a solution which worked for me. To call C# functions from a HTML attribute (like onBeforeUnload) you have to use JavaScript.

Let´s create a java script function named `callDotNetFunctionFromJS` like this (I created mine in a file named `callDotNetFunctionFromJS.js` which I saved in the `wwwroot` folder of the client project):

```
function callDotNetFunctionFromJS(functionName) {
    DotNet.invokeMethod('YourProjectName.Client', functionName);
}
```

Then create the function you want to call :

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void PageAboutToBeReloaded()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Page will be refreshed");
}
```

Important: Don´t forget to add `[JSInvokable]`, else the C# function can´t be called from the java script function. Also the method has to be **static**. If your method is non-static, please see my edit below.

In your .razor-file let´s add something like this:

```
<body onbeforeunload="callDotNetFunctionFromJS('PageAboutToBeReloaded')"></body>
```

Last but not least you have to add a reference to your .js-file to the `index.html`:

```
<script src="callDotNetFunctionFromJS.js"></script>
```

Now if you refresh the page where you want to be notified, you should see the output "Page will be refreshed". Pro tip: Activate `Preserve log` in the settings of the browser console to prevent the console to clear after refresh.

EDIT: If you want to call a non-static method, here you go:

The `PageAboutToBeReloaded` method has to look like this:

```
[JSInvokable]
public static void PageAboutToBeReloaded()
{
   callNonStaticFunction.Invoke();
}
```

For this to work, you have to add an Action at the top:

```
private static Action callNonStaticFunction;
```

Your `OnInitialized()` should look like this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    callNonStaticFunction = NonStaticFunction;
}
```

Now you can implement a non-static method to be called on page refresh:

```
void NonStaticFunction()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DEBUG: huhu");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0#after-component-render-onafterrenderasync) you can recognize the first render using the **OnAfterRender** or **OnAfterRenderAsync** methods with **firstRender** parameter.

```
 protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
{
  ...}
```